# Android Character.UnicodeBlock for various languages -help needed

Tags: android

ok, so like many others out there I have been trying to make an Android app that displays portions of my content in other languages. I thought Character.UnicodeBlock would be the obvious staring place but it isnt working for me.

I am calling the content from an xml file and using a font which I belives supports many different languages (DejaVuSans.ttf). I have tried making the content in the base language or actual unicode format but either way no joy.

Am I on the right track? or barking up the wrong tree? The annoying this is that I know it can be done as I have apps that display differnt languages! BTW I know about using various xml files for different locales but thats not what I am trying to do here.

This is my code so far

```
package com.ll.lang;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class homeActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

     TextView tv;
     tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);


     Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
      "fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf");

     Character.UnicodeBlock block = Character.UnicodeBlock.of (tv);
      tv.setTypeface(tf);                


    }

}
```